# Lightbox style dialogs in MFC App

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

Has anyone implemented Lightbox style background dimming on a modal dialog box in a MFC/non .net app.
I think the procedure would have to be something like:

steps:

1. Get dialog parent HWND or CWnd*
2. Get the rect of the parent window and draw an overlay with a translucency over that window
3. allow the dialog to do it's modal draw routine, e.g DoModal()

Are there any existing libraries/frameworks to do this, or what's the best way to drop a translucent overlay in MFC?
**edit** Here's a mockup of what i'm trying to achieve if you don't know what 'lightbox style' means
**Some App**:
[image]

with a lightbox dialog box
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I did* based on Brian's links
First create a dialog resource with the properties:

- border **FALSE**
- 3D look **FALSE**
- client edge **FALSE**
- Popup style
- static edge **FALSE**
- Transparent **TRUE**
- Title bar **FALSE**

and you should end up with a dialog window with no frame or anything, just a grey box.
override the Create function to look like this:

```
BOOL LightBoxDlg::Create(UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParentWnd)
{

    if(!CDialog::Create(nIDTemplate, pParentWnd))
        return false;
    RECT rect;
    RECT size;

    GetParent()->GetWindowRect(&rect);
    size.top = 0;
    size.left = 0;
    size.right = rect.right - rect.left;
    size.bottom = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    SetWindowPos(m_pParentWnd,rect.left,rect.top,size.right,size.bottom,NULL);

    HWND hWnd=m_hWnd;  
    SetWindowLong (hWnd , GWL_EXSTYLE ,GetWindowLong (hWnd , GWL_EXSTYLE ) | WS_EX_LAYERED ) ;
    typedef DWORD (WINAPI *PSLWA)(HWND, DWORD, BYTE, DWORD);
    PSLWA pSetLayeredWindowAttributes;
    HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary (_T("user32"));
    pSetLayeredWindowAttributes = 
        (PSLWA) GetProcAddress(hDLL,"SetLayeredWindowAttributes");
    if (pSetLayeredWindowAttributes != NULL) 
    {
        /*
        * Second parameter RGB(255,255,255) sets the colorkey 
        * to white LWA_COLORKEY flag indicates that color key 
        * is valid LWA_ALPHA indicates that ALphablend parameter 
        * is valid - here 100 is used
        */
        pSetLayeredWindowAttributes (hWnd, 
            RGB(255,255,255), 100, LWA_COLORKEY|LWA_ALPHA);
    }


    return true;
}
```

then create a small black bitmap in an image editor (say 48x48) and import it as a bitmap resource (in this example IDB_BITMAP1)
override the WM_ERASEBKGND message with:

```
BOOL LightBoxDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{

    BOOL bRet = CDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);

    RECT rect;
    RECT size;
    m_pParentWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);
    size.top = 0;
    size.left = 0;
    size.right = rect.right - rect.left;
    size.bottom = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    CBitmap cbmp;
    cbmp.LoadBitmapW(IDB_BITMAP1);
    BITMAP bmp;
    cbmp.GetBitmap(&bmp);
    CDC memDc;
    memDc.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    memDc.SelectObject(&cbmp);
    pDC->StretchBlt(0,0,size.right,size.bottom,&memDc,0,0,bmp.bmWidth,bmp.bmHeight,SRCCOPY);

    return bRet;
}
```

Instantiate it in the DoModal of the desired dialog, Create it like a Modal Dialog i.e. on the stack(or heap if desired), call it's Create manually, show it then create your actual modal dialog over the top of it:

```
INT_PTR CAboutDlg::DoModal()
{
    LightBoxDlg Dlg(m_pParentWnd);//make sure to pass in the parent of the new dialog
    Dlg.Create(LightBoxDlg::IDD);
    Dlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    BOOL ret = CDialog::DoModal();

    Dlg.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    return ret;
}
```

and this results in something **exactly** like my mock up above

*there are still places for improvment, like doing it without making a dialog box to begin with and some other general tidyups.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to create a window and set the transparency. There is an MFC [CGlassDialog sample on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CGlassDialog.aspx) that might help you. There is also an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/quaker1.aspx) on how to do this with the Win32 APIs.

Comment: this looks like what i'm looking for. I'll try it out and report back :)